# Issue with cordova build android

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, gradle

I am working on an application with cordova. When i try to build it with android it throws error i am unable to figure out how do i fix this.

[This is the snapshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u433K.png)

Here is the requirements which shows by c:\testapp>cordova requirements

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-23
Gradle: installed
```

Any kind of help will appreciated.

Comment: try with updating your sdk

Comment: Gradle daemon set automatically on first installation, may be there were any problem while installing cordova so try `npm uninstall cordova -g` and then again `npm install cordova -g`

Comment: Thanks @kirankumar Dafda.  Its Working.

Comment: Great, then you can accept my answer and close the question!

Answer (score 0):

Gradle daemon set automatically on first installation,

may be there were any problem while installing cordova

so try

```
npm uninstall cordova -g
```

and then again

```
npm install cordova -g
```